# Yande-map-kit поисковая система не работает так как в Yandex вебсайте

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandexmapkit

Например я хочу найти "vokzal namangan" в моей приложени, но yandex map kit не выдаёт никакие результаты. Точно такой же запрос я задаю в яндекс map в вебсайте то работает прекрасно.Скриншот с приложении [image: Скриншот с приложении]

[image: Скриншот с Yandex веб сайта]

Мой код:

```
  Future<void> querySuggestions() async {
    final query = queryController.text;

    print('Suggest query: $query');

    final resultWithSession = YandexSuggest.getSuggestions(
        text: query,
        boundingBox: BoundingBox(
            northEast: Point(latitude: 38.439325, longitude: 65.848850),
            southWest: Point(latitude: 42.009998, longitude: 72.783439)),
        suggestOptions: SuggestOptions(
            suggestType: SuggestType.geo,
            suggestWords: true,
            userPosition: widget.point));
    resultWithSession.result.then((SuggestSessionResult value) {
      if (value.items!.isNotEmpty) {
        visibilityList = true;
        this.suggestItems = value.items;
      } else {
        visibilityList = false;
      }
      setState(() {});
    });
  }
```

Comment: Приведите пример запроса, отправляемого в сервис, или пример кода, которым вы реализовали поиск в мобильном приложении.

Comment: Я поправил пост и добавил код, также добавил результат с яндекс вебсайта чтоб можно было сравнить с моим.